# when clicking update after page editing it returns this page not working in wordpress

Tags: pages, buttons

wordpress page update button not working correctlyl,it returns page not working
other pages of my wordpress site also doing the same..
Give some ideas you know..
Thanks in advance[image].

Comment: Is there anything in your error logs? Need more information...

Comment: I would say it's a problem with your Visual Composer or some plugin, because if I access the site, I see a lot of Visual Composer 'shortcodes',